# Use java enterprise edition to read from a PDF file difficulties using PDFBox

Tags: pdf, jakarta-ee, pdfbox

I wanted build a JEE program to text from multiple read PDF invoices.

Find out invoice 3 three things from pdf file invoice number, invoice date and invoice amount.

The invoice would be from different types(data may not be at same place/style in the PDF file).

After reading the required fields from the PDF display them in a table and sum up the invoice amount to get the total expanse.

I tried using PDFBox by Apache but the problem arises with PDFBox was that it reads the **Bold** characters first from the PDF and the reads the normal character. That makes it difficult to judge from where to read the data because all the PDF might not use the same design.

Also upload PDF file to the server before reading.
[image: PDF FILE]
[image: Text Read By PDFBox]

Comment: Have you tried the sort option?

Comment: A good question indeed. You set `SortByPosition` to `false`, so you explicitly are not interested in the order on the page but the order of drawing.